# AWS SDK v3 Assume role for a client

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, aws-sts

I'm writing a Node JS app using AWS JS SDK v3. I am correctly using STS to assume role and retrieve credentials. The assume call response is such:

```json
{
    "$metadata": {
        "httpStatusCode": 200,
        "requestId": "xxx",
        "attempts": 1,
        "totalRetryDelay": 0
    },
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "xxx",
        "SecretAccessKey": "xxx",
        "SessionToken": "xxx",
        "Expiration": "2021-02-26T15:40:17.000Z"
    },
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "xxx",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::xxx"
    }
}
```

I am taking the credentials and passing them to a DynamoDBClient constructor (along with region).

```js
import { DynamoDBClient, ListTablesCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
    
public getTablesList(region: string) {
    const credentials = await getCredentialsFromSTS(region);
    const clientParams = Object.assign(credentials, region); // This just merges two JSONs into one
    const dbClient = new DynamoDBClient(clientParams);
    const command = new ListTablesCommand({});
    const response = await dbClient.send(command);
    console.log(response);
}
```

What I get in the response is a list of only the tables of the account, that runs my code. The tables in the account where I am assuming the role are not present. Maybe I am assuming the role wrongly? I tried to package the credentials in a "Credentials" key, but that didn't help either.

```js
const clientParams = Object.assign({ Credentials: credentials }, region);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Maybe the DDBClient is not assuming it as it should, but is there a way to check the assumed role for the DBClient? I found a namespace called RoleInfo in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/globals.html), but I don't know how to invoke it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read the documentation of the DynamoDBClient parameter object: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#constructor-property

The credentials fields are lower-case whereas in the STS result they are upper-case.

There are also more errors in your code, such as the `Object.assign(credentials, region);` call. `region` here is a `string`, so by assigning it into `credentials` you will not get a property named "region" with the value of that `region` variable, but you will get numeric properties, each with one character of the `region` string.

The correct initialization should be:

```javascript
const credentials = await getCredentialsFromSTS(region);
const dbClient = new DynamoDBClient({
  region: region,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: credentials.AccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: credentials.SecretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: credentials.SessionToken,
  }
});
```